# VueJS Bind prop only if data variable is true

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

How can I bind a property only when a variable is set to `true`?

```html
<template>
    <v-list-tile :class="{[$color]: isItemSelected, [$primaryText]: isItemSelected}" :href="route">
        <v-list-tile-action>
            <v-icon :color="$primaryIcon">{{ icon }}</v-icon>
        </v-list-tile-action>
        <v-list-tile-content>
            <v-list-tile-title>{{ title }}</v-list-tile-title>
        </v-list-tile-content>
    </v-list-tile>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'list-tile-text-icon',
        props: ['icon', 'title', 'route'],
        data: () => ({
            isItemSelected: false
        }),
        created() {
            this.isItemSelected = window.location.href === this.route;
        }
    }
</script>
```

On line 4 I need to bind in `:color="$primaryColor"` only when the `isItemSelected` variable is equal to `true`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The values used in `v-bind` are JavaScript **expressions**, thus you can use the  [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```html
<v-icon :color="isItemSelected ? $primaryIcon : null">
```

*Note*: I'm calling it `v-bind` because `:` is just a shorthand to `v-bind`. I.e. `:color=""` is the same as `v-bind:color=""`

Answer (score 1):

[Vue class and style binding doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#ad)

this is the offical document about vue class and style binding,

detail:

```
<v-list-title :class="{someClassYouDefine: isItemSelected}"> </v-list-title>
```

then write the style you want

```
<style>
   .someClassYouDefine {
      color: $primaryColor;
   }
</style>
```